# Filtrar dados de uma lista em Python

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista que segui esse padrão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de gerar outra lista com os dados que estão entre os números de um caractere tipo entre 0 e 1, 1 e 1 etc..
Exemplo:

```
[['992', '1109778', '19/01/22', '101005', '4.144,00', '2.188.842,42'], ['1726', '1109773', '19/01/22', '100037', '994,00', '2.189.836,42']]
```

Comment: Com todo o respeito é segunda vez que está pedindo para fazer algo para você que não faz o menor sentido. Não duplique as publicações, as edite e as esclareça.

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorânica, minha primeira interação aqui na plataforma.

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema de outra forma. vlwww

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem sua pergunta, mas acredito que o que você está procurando a solução seja "expressão regular". Segue um exemplo de como pegar somente números 0 ou 1 numa lista em python.

import re
lista = ["0", "1", "123", "1", "12/03/2022", "1", "5.000,00"]
novalista = list(filter(lambda v: re.match('^[01]{1}$', v), lista))

Comment: Obrigado, não é bem isso que quero rsrs tipo eu quero pegar apenas os valores que estão entre os valores de 1 caracter. Tipo: entre 0 e 1 alí na lista tem 992, 1109778 etc. Eu quero esses valores em formato de uma nova lista.